# Visual Studio Code: switch-case block content indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I enter the following code:

```
function actionToAppState(action) {
  switch (action) {
    case START:
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

The `doSomething()` line should be indented by one more tab. Indeed, I select the function and format it with <kbd>Ctrl+K+F</kbd>:

```
function actionToAppState(action) {
  switch (action) {
    case START:
      doSomething()
  }
}
```

Why isn't that line indented as I type? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to "User Settings":

```
editor.formatOnType: true
```

Or more precisely, open **File -> Preferences -> Settings**, then search for "**formatontype**", then set `editor.formatOnType` to `true`.

Comment: It also additionally formats the current line after I type it in and hit Enter. VSCode is weird.

Comment: In my case switch case always 4 space indent (which is not following my indent setting), but formatOnType make it fix automatically.

Comment: This doesn't really help me as it doesn't unindent after break;. It leaves me with funky looking switch-cases, not to mention that it affects a lot more than just switch-cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code formatting shortcuts

VSCode on Windows - Shift + Alt + F

VSCode on MacOS - Shift + Option + F

VSCode on Ubuntu - Ctrl + Shift + I

You can also customize this shortcut using preference setting if needed.